# When will Android have a public Calendar API?

Tags: android

Is someone from Google able to advise when the Android SDK is likely to include a public API for reading/writing event data to the user's calendar?

Searching the forums I see that this is a much desired feature by many developers but I haven't seen any indication as to when (or even if) this need will be addressed.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You can post this to be asked during Android "office hours" on IRC soon: http://moderator.appspot.com/#15/e=120951&t=126bf1

Answer (score 8):

according to one post on the dev group, regarding calendar access:

> Definitely not for 1.6, very unlikely
>   for 2.0, and it is probably a safe
>   assumption that it is not public
>   because it is likely to change in the
>   future

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8bb14b62eca6b04e/

not sure what the future plans are, but there is an interesting hack to gain read access to the calendar via the undocumented api:

- Accessing the internal calendar database inside Google Android applications: 
  http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

of course if your android device is online, you can read/write through the standard calendar data api:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html

Comment: You can pretty much count on the calendar provider changing in the future...  for example at whatever point the calendar supports multiple accounts.  So if you use these private APIs, be prepared and expect your app to break in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Hooray! A public calendar api will be available in Ice Cream Sandwich:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html

Direct link to api docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b207cad25a2a29e5/911d26fa97502e98?lnk=gst&q=calendar+API#911d26fa97502e98

Seems android official people insist that developers should not use "undocumented, unsupported API" and they recommend the online API: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

But this obviously requires the end users to keep their mobiles online, Android app -> HTTP -> Calendar Data API -> HTTP -> Android Calendar (via sync). Currently android end users are much more sensitive about the INTERNET permission (combined with other personal info permissions) due to recent malignant softwares in Android Market...

There is a wheel already, good enough, we don't want to create another one, right?

Answer (score 2):

This article may help you: http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276
It's based on reverse engineering and tested on Android 1.6, so it may not work on newer versions.