# How do I access the Calendar/Events from Android SDK?

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to write an app that relies on Calendar events.  I was going to write it as a service, and just have it check the calendar from time to time, but I found out that the SDK does not offer direct access to the Calendar yet.  So is there any other way to access Events?

Maybe a broadcast when an event starts and stops?  Something like that, I'm not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will Android have a public Calendar API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023557/when-will-android-have-a-public-calendar-api)

Comment: Aint there a database/content provider where all the calender events are stored?

Answer (score 2):

> So is there any other way to access
>   Events?

The same way you would outside of Android, using Google GData APIs for Google Calendar.