# android - google calendar

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to develop an app that reads info from google calendar on Android.
The question is, is there a way to connect to the local calendar or should I use the google calendar API and read the info from the internet?  (or maybe another way)

as far as I know, there are ways to connect to the local calendar, but non of them are official ones, and it breaks in different versions of android.

(by google calendar API I mean  http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/ )

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already answered your question yourself.

1. There is no official way to access Calendar inside Android. There is a hack for read access: [When will Android have a public Calendar API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023557/when-will-android-have-a-public-calendar-api)
2. It's definitely better to use Google official Calendar API, as it's official, supported, future-proof and write-enabled.

The only downside to using Google Calendar API is that this is an online API and you need to have connectivity. You can work around this if you save the data and implement your own [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html). Then your Calendar data will be synced when all other data on the device is synced.

Answer (score 0):

> "as far as I know, there are ways to
>   connect to the local calendar, but non
>   of them are official ones, and it
>   breaks in different versions of
>   android."

This has been my experience as well.  I would recommend using the internet Google Calendar API.