# Secure Android with cryptography

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm thinking of buy an android phone, but I'm a little bit scared about the security and privacy because in my palm I had in contacts and calendar a lot of private information. First I thought it could be solved by trying to sync without google, but in the last time I get a lot of information of security holes in android-apps to that I can't be sure that the phone self isn't compromised. I don't mean criminal apps, I mean criminal websites or apps with installed in background.

So my idea was to encrypt all entries [Update4]( only the description and text based field will be encrypted, not the time )[/Update4] of the calendar and contacts. This means writing an app, where I can define a security level for each record. Than I can set which entries should be decrypted and which not. So if I'm surfing in the www I can encrypted all and it will be save. Even if I sync with google I can go this way (Update: So google only has the encrypted data). After that I decrypt the records.
Of course this is sometimes inconvenient, but I fear security is always inconvenient. [Update2] To make it clear, the data wont be decrypted on the fly, so if the data are encrypted and I open the calendar app I only will the the time and an encrypted description.[/Update2]

[Update3] What I don't want to do is to hack the android-system, meaning to root the phone or install a special firmware. Furthermore I don't want to invest weeks for development, so programming a new PIM-app is not an option. I simply want to take every record from the calender/contact database and encrypt the critical data. As far as I know there is an api to read and write such data. [/Update3]

So my questions are

1. Is this possible to implement?
2. Can I test it with the emulator or is the calendar and
       contacts app not part of the emulator?

Thanks 
Niels

PS: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023557/when-will-android-have-a-public-calendar-api) there is no public api to calendar, so it can't work :-(

Comment: "2. Can I test it with the emulator or is there no calendar app and contacts app?" I don't understand quite well this question.

Comment: As far as I know the calendar and contacts app are not open source. I want to test it without buy an android phone, so I need an emulator with has this apps to have the possibility to test. Hope this and the changing of the question makes it more clear.

Comment: How do you want to restrict the access to your private data on the phone by syncing them with Google?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I want to sync only encrypted data. So do read them you need a firefox-plugin with decrypt them and a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to implement?

Is it possible to write a calendar app and a contacts app that store their data locally in an encrypted form? Yes.

Is it possible to modify the existing Calendar and Dialtacts apps to have this feature? Only by modifying the firmware.

Is it possible to sync encrypted calendar/contacts data with Google? Probably not.

> Can I test it with the emulator or is the calendar and contacts app not part of the emulator?

Can you test your own independent applications on the emulator? Yes.

Can you test your own modified firmware on the emulator? Yes.

Comment: I thought I could encrypt the entries of the calendar. So if the description is encrypted, the calendar app will show the crypted text. Writing an own calendar and contacts app seems to complicated for me, or miss I something

Comment: @neils: Writing a calendar or contacts application should be about an order of magnitude simpler than is modifying the Android firmware to encrypt stuff that was not designed to be so encrypted. Hence, ff writing a calendar or contacts app is too complicated, then everything you have written about is too complicated.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why I must hack the firmware? I thought there is an api to read and write calendar data. So I read the decrypted ones and write the encrypted or other way around.

Comment: @neils: You are welcome to attempt to send encrypted data to the Google Calendar GData API. However, since your dates and everything will be encrypted, presumably your requests will fail with an error, since they will not be valid data. All of that holds true for contacts as well, except there you at least have a supported on-device API, albeit one that will not support encrypted data.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't want to encrypt the time. Only the critical data like description and notes (if the last is possible). The same at the contact data. There it could give trouble with numbers and mail-adresses if there validation exists. Sorry for ask so unspecified.

Comment: @neils: If you Base64-encode the encrypted stuff, with luck, you won't break anything. And, you still have to write an Android calendar and contacts app to make use of your encrypted data, since the built-in ones will just display the Base64-encoded encrypted stuff.

Comment: That sounds good. It's clear that the normal app would show the Base64-endcoded encrypted stuff. How ever I would only encrypt them if I am online. Most of the time they will be in clear text.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the android emulator.  You will have access to all the open source parts of android, and unlike with the phones it is relatively possible to install altered versions, since you have root on the emulator automatically.  Plus it's free - or I mean, it will only cost your time.

If you then conclude that your project is workable, look either for a phone that is known to be rootable and has a working open source platform build for it (ie, something cynagenmod or similar runs on) or else a phone sold as a developer model.

While it's possible you will be able to do what you want purely by writing applications within the bounds of the SDK, it's likely you will end up wanting to modify the platform to some degree, primarily to stop it from automatically doing things with cleartext data or at least to uninstall the defaults apps where you might accidentally do something with cleartext.  So ease of doing that should guide your purchase decision more than features of a closed vendor build.

Comment: See [Update 3] I don't want to hack the phone or write a great app. But if I understand you right I only have access to the opensource part so not to the calendar-app :-(

Comment: If you don't want to "hack" and you don't want to write a new application, then please don't buy an android phone until someone is already marketing one with the capabilities that you want.  At present, you'd probably be happier with a blackberry.

Comment: Well it's Ok for me to write a new app, but I don't have the time for a great one like a calendar and contacts. I thinks to write an encrypt/decrypt functionality shouldn't be to complicated. But perhaps I should really check blackberry, but I don't know if it will be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really seem like you really understand or know the Android security and application installation principle.

In the first place there is no application which installs another application in the background. It just does not work that way. Every application which needs to be installed will only be installed if the user clicks on install.

There might be malicious applications (i.e. applications which log and send the data you enter or allow it to access other data to a server) no doubt but an user will be presented permissions list an application requires which allows the user to check if he is OK with that application to access the internet even tho that application would (logically) not need access to it for instance.

Now to answer your question if you can modify the pre-installed calendar application. No you can't do that without building from source. You basically would have to fetch the calendar project and modify the stuff you need. You'll probably need to modify other parts of the system too I'm not sure without checking it myself. If it would be possible to do so then we would really have some serious problems.

Due to Androids security model an application won't have access to any other application if that application does not explicitly allows that.

You won't get around getting your hands dirty with coding or possibly even custom system images.

Comment: Probably I don't understand the security model of Android. I have written down my knowledge here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421136/what-are-possible-security-issues-in-android , because I don't want to discuss it here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar

But don't expect to do anything with it without a fair amount of hacking.  Most of the included apps will not build as SDK apps (ie, other than as part of a full firmware build) without deep-reaching changes - though I admit I haven't tried this particular one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and the warning that it could become difficult. At least this should give me the possibility to test the calendar on the emulator.