# What are possible security issues in Android

Tags: android, security

For understanding how strong data should be secured on an Android device I want to understand which attacks are possible. I started to write down my knowledge and hope that I get corrections, where I'm wrong or where I'm missing something. I first assume that Google don't be evil, so will ignores attacks from google themselves.

Each application is signed and runs under his own user-id, so an app can only reads data which belongs to him, except the app creates a public storage. Furthermore app which are sign with the same key can share data. 
If an application want to get special rights like reading or writing to calendar or contacts the user must accept it.

So by default it's a secure design. Unfortunately every system can have security issues, so that the system become corrupted. On Desktop-Systems regular updates are common practice. On the android it depends on the vendor and is except the Nexus mostly bad. So it could be that there are security holes open for a long period.

So how could an android phone be attacked?

1. Google can delete and install apps silently ([Link](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/25/remote-kill-and-install-on-google-android/)). If someone hacks this mechanism, an attacker can install arbitrary apps on a device. Unsure if this app has automatically all rights it wants to have. This doesn't happens till now, but it's possible. You can only protect your phone by checking regularly all installed apps and there rights. This mechanism can be misused by a hacker.
2. Malicious applications can do a lot evil things, but if you don't give every app the rights the apps wanted and think a little bit, you can protect your phone.
3. Some security holes in the browser or the system allows an app to get root-access. In this case the app can do everything it wanted. I don't know any protection against this. As far as I know android has such security holes, so this is the most dangerous issue.

So in summary the only secure protection of data seems to be encryption. Depending on how secure your data must be with a default key or an individual key (in other words a password).

Comment: Encryption creates the new problem of where to store the key. You at least need it when you want to decrypt the data, at which point something malicious with root access can easily intercept it.

Comment: That was I mean with default and individual key. If you use a password it's secure.

Comment: `1` is insignificant AFAICT, because you already trust Google 100%, as you are running code from them, and constantly receiving updated code from them. `3` will never be fixed, as it's a fundamental flaw in the OS, but as long as nobody has a reason to hack you, you wont get hacked, most people aren't smart enough to exploit these kind of things so you only really have to worry about published 0days, and viruses, which probably wont harm you much apart from being annoying.

Comment: `1` is significant, because it can hacked by other people who misused this functionality.`3` Android is a popular platform, so it is worth to hack it, because you have many victims. You are right that it is a fundamental flaw, the problem is that you can't get security updates **easily** combined with popular platform.

Comment: You should try asking this on the [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've found these PDF's, maybe they can help: <strike>[slides](https://www.isecpartners.com/files/iSEC_Android_Exploratory_Blackhat_2009.pdf), [paper](https://www.isecpartners.com/files/iSEC_Securing_Android_Apps.pdf)</strike> (more than 2 years old).

edit:

- [a new link for the slides](http://b00ks-d0c.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/b00ks-d0c/research/Mobile%20and%20Malware/iSEC_Android_Exploratory_Blackhat_2009.pdf)
- [a new link for the paper](https://www.nccgroup.trust/globalassets/our-research/us/whitepapers/isec_securing_android_apps.pdf)

Comment: 404 error :(, documents are not available anymore.

Comment: @Anaseh feel free to update the links yourself next time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Google can delete and install apps silently. If someone hacks this mechanism, an attacker can install arbitrary apps on a device. Unsure if this app has automatically all rights it wants to have. This doesn't happens till now, but it's possible. You can only protect your phone by checking regularly all installed apps and there rights.

Delete may be silent, but the only push-install mechanism I know about is to use the firmware update mechanism, and that is not silent - the phone reboots twice.

> Malicious applications can do a lot evil things, but if you don't give every app the rights the apps wanted and think a little bit, you can protect your phone.

Unfortunately, you cannot decline to grant permissions, you can only decline to install an app that requests more than you want to grant.  And some permissions are quite broad, so an app may legitimately need a tiny part of some permission, but get the whole thing.

> Some security holes in the browser or the system allows an app to get root-access. In this case the app can do everything it wanted. I don't know any protection against this. As far as I know android has such security holes, so this is the most dangerous issue.

On the other hand, these security holes are unfortunately what the owners of most devices must rely on in if they wish to to be able to install custom firmware, since most consumer phones were not designed to permit this.  Knowledge about android security exploits is not much behind that of conventional linux distributions (most of the root exploit are inherited linux kernel exploits, not android exploits, since android has few components with root authority).

Comment: I added a link to the silent install. You are right that the security issues are the same as on every desktop or linux system. The difference is that I can update my linux system daily. I get security patches really fast. Google only fix security issues in new versions. If you have luck your phone manufactor will deliver the new version to you, month after the release. So android-phones are like desktop pcs without and security updates.

Comment: Ok, apparently there's a package install to match the uninstall, but seeing as your link includes pictures of the notification screens that result, I don't see why you want to call this a silent mechanism.  In terms of patching, you can leverage an exploit to gain full access to your device and then patch that and any future exploits yourself.  Essentially the difference from an ordinary linux is that the tivoized default installs makes the existence of kernel exploits as much of a gift to users as they are to attackers.